# WinPE with Powershell GUI boot into iso-files

Tags: powershell, bootloader, winpe

I have created a USB-drive with WinPE and I created a Powershell script with GUI which is automatically loaded. It has a button to open CMD, a reboot and a shutdown button.

I want to be able to run Memtest from my menu, by booting its ISO file.

I have added the Imdrive to my WinPE and I am able to mount the ISO but I don´t know how to run it?

Answer (score 0):

As Memtest boots its own version of Linux you'll need to use a boot manager to be able to boot multiple OS's as you can't run Linux *within* WinPE.

Something like [rEFInd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/) would make this easier for you ([small tutorial on using rEFInd](http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/127-make-dual-32-64bit-pe#TOC-Adding-other-UEFI-.EFI-payloads)).

Personally, I would just use [Hirens BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) as it will already contain everything you'd ever need.

Comment: I will look into it, thanks.
My thoughts was maybe partition the USB drive and reboot to specified partition in this case Memtest partition but I don´t know how to reboot to speciied drive or partition from WinPE.

Comment: Anyone know if it is possible to partition the USB drive and change the Metro Bootloader for WinPE so that I can choose from there which partition to boot from?